# How do I get all 1x, 2x and 3x images to scale the entire screen perfectly on all iOS device screens?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have read the 1x, 2x and 3x named image information for ios devices, but would that not cause scaling/image distortion when fitting it to an entire screen?

For example, the 3x can be handled by many iOS devices, but if you go from one to another, the screen resolutions/displays aren't a perfect 1 to 1 scale, so if I designed the 3x image to perfectly match say an iPhone 12, if another device uses the 3x image but with a different screen ratio, the background image fit to screen would then be skewed, correct?

Is there a way to avoid this?  Some suggestions said have an image for every device/resolution and pick that image accordingly, but there is a long list of the devices, and it seems like overkill and a tedious solution.  There must be something more elegant, unless I'm wrong.

Comment: It won't be skewed. Just make 1x, 2x, and 3x, then let Xcode handle the rest.

Comment: Good comment, and *great* answer. What's the **specific** issue? Can you post something I could duplicate? I can tell you are concerned about images... does that mean a launch screen? Maybe a `UIImageView`? Or something more granular? Bottom line - **NO**, you **DO NOT** need an image for **every** device/resolution. No way. But without more detail of what is your *true* issue? It's hard to help.

Comment: My issue is that I want to use an image to be a background image for an app.  I want it to fill the entire screen, regardless of device (iPhone or iPad).  My issue is that, if I just have one background image to span across ALL these devices, named as 1x, 2x, and 3x, each of the devices will grab the appropriate one.  However, aspect ratios across all of them are not exact, so a 2x on an iPhone and iPad for example, if I lock it to screen size with code/constraints, one will skew.  Same with scale to fill.  Aspect fit will have dead space somewhere.  Aspect fill will crop.

Comment: Continuing my response, I just do not want any skewing, stretching, cropping, etc but with the minimal amount of these 1x, 2x, 3x images.  It seems like the only TRUE way to avoid this is to make 1x, 2x and 3x background images for every aspect ratio, check which aspect ratio the device has and assign the appropriate background image.  Sorry for lack of detail in the original question.

Comment: If you don't want any scaling or cropping then you will need to make numerous images. There is no other way that an entire image can fill variously sized screens.

Answer (score 0):

You need to preserve the aspect ratio of the image when it is scaled to fit the UIImageView. You can do this by setting the image view's content mode to either aspect fit or aspect fill depending on your requirements.